# Angular Abstract control remove error

Tags: angular

I want a way to remove a specific error from a form control and not clear all error.

```
control.setError({'firstError': true})
```

and to remove that specific error like

```
control.removeError({'firstError}) and not control.setError({null})
```

I tried

```
control.setError({'firstError': false})
```

but didn't work.

Any help. Thanks

angular 4.1.1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can remove like this:

```
control.setErrors({'firstError': null})
```

Comment: I believe it is `control.setErrors( {'firstError': null} )`

Comment: control.setError({}) doing this works. However, I do think it will remove ALL errors from the control, not just one.

Comment: I believe it is control.setErrors( null )

Comment: Maybe it was working at some point in time, but it does not work now.
You simply can't remove a single error from the control like this.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21564

Comment: In case you want to remove all errors from control then use `control.setErrors(null)` and in case you want to remove CERTAIN error then use `control.setErrors({firstError: null})`

Comment: This is not the right solution in 2021 with Angular 12, please check the other answers below.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets to which answer exactly are you referring?

Comment: @MikhailRatner https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186871/134120

Comment: @MikhailRatner please also note that you will have to add the following lines, you can find them below in one of the other answers here. It seems that Angular wants `control.errors` to be null in order for the control to be considered valid: `if (Object.keys(control.errors || {}).length === 0) {
    control.setErrors(null);
  }`

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets Thank you for that.  I see this as a design flaw in Angular.  Since you can do something like `control.setErrors({firstError: null})` or `control.setErrors({firstError: false})`, it seems logical when testing for validity, it should also be checking if each error that *is* set has a value that is either null or false (or undefined?).  Then again I haven't done a deep dive on this, so I could be off on this opinion.

Answer (score 55):

You can remove error with:

```
control.setErrors({'firstError': null});

control.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: except that it is `control.setErrors()`

Comment: Keep in mind that with this solution, control.invalid remains true bc control.errors.length > 0

Comment: `option` param of `updateValueAndValidity()` determine how the control propagates changes and emits events, so if you do not want to emit the value to `valueChanges` subscribers you have to set `control.updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent: false})`

Comment: Perfect, especially since it allows to nullify just a single error and not reset the entire controls Validators.

Comment: won't work! No matter what value property has if existing control is invalid

Answer (score 42):

First, you should check your field for has this error.
next, remove it.
And for end you are need to update all errors in your controll.

Something like this in validator function:

```
if (control.hasError('firstError')) {
      delete control.errors['firstError'];
      control.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: This solutions is great because it avoids the `control.invalid remains true bc control.errors.length > 0` issue that some of the other answers have.

Comment: Indeed, in 2021 with Angular 12 this is the best solution.

Answer (score 13):

Much has already been stated in other posts to this question (e.g. delete the error property (which still leaves the control flagged as `invalid`), issues with `updateValueAndValidity()` in `changeHandlers` (infinite loop) etc). Putting it all together I now use the below small function, which leaves other errors untouched and resets the invalid flag if no other errors remain:

```
removeFormControlError(control: AbstractControl, errorName: string) {
  if (control?.errors && control?.errors[errorName]) {
    delete control.errors[errorName];
    if (Object.keys(control.errors).length === 0) {
      control.setErrors(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was about to criticize this because .errors is a readonly property.  But of course that doesn't make the list immutable, so actually this is a fantastic idea!  I was about to write something to the same effect that required first setErrors(null) followed by a loop to restore every error that had been present except the one you wanted removed.  But your solution is much more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

I came from this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21564) and try this little workaround

Using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
if ( control.hasError('errorToRemove') ) {
  const { errorToRemove, ...errors } = control.errors;
  control.setErrors(errors);
  control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

You can also try the [omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit) or [pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) `lodash` functions, to respectively omit or pick a series of errors that you can set to the control later.

```js
const errors = pick(control.errors, ['onlyErrorsToKeep']);
control.setErrors(errors);
control.updateValueAndValidity();
```

```js
const errors = omit(control.errors, ['allErrorsToRemove']);
control.setErrors(errors);
control.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: ```const { errorToRemove, ...errors } = control.errors;```
Aren't you just removing the first error from control.errors and then setting this back?

How are you guaranteeing that error is actually the error you want to remove?

Comment: @ChrisWeber There are cases you need to, for example, remove matDatepickerFilter error manually, so this is a nice example

Comment: should use `const { errorToRemove, errors } = control.errors;` otherwise `errors` will be empty object `{}`.

Answer (score 5):

I am using **Dynamic Forms** and I wanted to clear the error of one component from another. I tried **.setErrors()** method but it was not working. The working solution for me is listed below.

```
clearControlError( control: AbstractControl ): void {
    const err = control.errors;
    if (err) {
        delete err['timeNotValid'];
        if (!Object.keys(err).length) {
            control.setErrors(null);
        } else {
            control.setErrors(err);
        }
    }
}
```

now I can clear error of any AbstractControl type control by passing it to the function like this.

```
this.clearControlError(this.formBase.parent.get('startTime'));
```

or

```
this.clearControlError(this.form.controls['startTime']);
```

Comment: This worked for me in a situation adding a new FormGroup at the end of a FormArray, which was immediately triggering the Validators.required error on the controls in the just-added FormGroup.  This problem was occurring for me within the same Component.  One thing I did need to add was to call the clearControlError() method from within a setTimeout().  A short delay was needed for the error to be available to be cleared.

Answer (score 4):

```
control.setErrors({'firstError': null});
```

Will not working anymore.  You need to use a helper method.  Copied from https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21564#issuecomment-480569715

```
public static removeErrors(keys: string[], control: AbstractControl) {
  if (!control || !keys || keys.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  const remainingErrors = keys.reduce((errors, key) => {
    delete errors[key];
    return errors;
  }, { ...control.errors });

  control.setErrors(remainingErrors);

  if (Object.keys(control.errors || {}).length === 0) {
    control.setErrors(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

for clear all validations you can use `markAsUntouched` function like below.
for example for form group controls:

```
for (let controlsKey in this.formGroup.controls) {
      let control = this.formGroup.controls[controlsKey];
      control.markAsUntouched();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I simply used [updateValueAndValidity()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity) which is used to re-calculate the value and validation.
The below is my validator function which validates my `grossWeight`.

```
validateWeights(formGroup) {
    let netWeight = formGroup.get('netWeight');
    let grossWeight = formGroup.get('grossWeight');

    if (parseFloat(netWeight.value) > parseFloat(grossWeight.value)) {
        grossWeight.setErrors({ 'customError': true });
        netWeight.setErrors({ 'customError': true });
    } else {
        if(netWeight.errors && netWeight.errors['customError']) {
            netWeight.updateValueAndValidity();
        }
        if (grossWeight.errors && grossWeight.errors['customError']) {
            grossWeight.updateValueAndValidity();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This would work great if you were not already in a handler for `valueChanges`. I'm validating controls based on other parts of the form's value changing. So, `updateValueAndValidity` causes an infinite loop.

Comment: `updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false })` @jkyoutsey

Answer (score 2):

If we are dynamically adding and removing errors, as of Angular 8, the above examples simply don't work.  I'm adding errors based upon the state of other controls. i.e. I have two customers defined with the same email address.  This is the only solution I could find that actually works.

```js
tap(duplicateError => {
    /* Note to future self...
     * I'm beginning to hate AbstractControl.errors.
     * The email control can have multiple errors (required, email, and duplicate);
     * The ONLY way to clear an error is to not have it in the object that is passed to the setErrors call.
     * You CANNOT pass null or undefined! It will still be evaluated as an error!
     * This is also true if there are NO errors AT ALL. You cannot pass setErrors({}) or the control will be
     * invalid, even though there are no errors! You must call setErrors(null);
     * This is stupid, but it's the only way it works.
     * This code is concerned with setting/removing the duplicate error.
     */
    const email = this.form.get('email');
    // Clone the existing errors
    const existingErrors = { ...email.errors };
    // Ensure that duplicate error is removed (we're in the change handler for the duplicate error)
    delete existingErrors.duplicate;
    if (duplicateError) {
        // We have a new duplicate error, so add it.
        email.setErrors({ ...existingErrors, duplicate: duplicateError.errorMessage });
    } else if (Object.keys(existingErrors).length === 0) {
        // We have NO errors, so pass null
        email.setErrors(null);
    } else {
        // We have existing errors, but no new duplicate error. Pass the existing errors.
        email.setErrors(existingErrors);
    }
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.form.controls["field"].setErrors(null);
```

Comment: It would be a better answer if you explained your code instead of just dumping code.

Comment: more explicit than that, impossible

Comment: this will remove all errors. not necessarily what you want. most of the other answers take into account that there could be more than one error

Answer (score 0):

I was having this bug caused by using *ngIf to show some controls. I want to delete ALL errors and start from scratch this works:

```
Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).forEach(controlName => {
  if (controlName != "search") {
    let control = that.myForm.controls[controlName];
    if (control.errors) {
      let errorKeys = Object.keys(control.errors);
      errorKeys.forEach(key => {
        delete control.errors[key];
      })
    }
    control.setErrors(null);
    this.options[controlName + "Error"] = null;
  }
});
```

in my code I want to leave the "search" control alone, and I also clear the error strings I save in this.options.{controlName}Error