# Remove validation error from Formcontrol after changing its value using angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form with multiple FormControls. I validate the values of my FormControls after submitting the form. Lets say i get an validation error for a FormControl that saves the user's name. If the user changes the value, the validation error should disappear and he can submit the form again.

I have looked into  this question [Angular Abstract control remove error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069629/angular-abstract-control-remove-error) which has helped me deleting the error from the FormControl.

```
removeFormControlError(control: AbstractControl, errorName: string) {
    if (control?.errors && control?.errors[errorName]) {
      delete control.errors[errorName];
      if (Object.keys(control.errors).length === 0) {
        control.setErrors(null);
      }
    }
  }
```

I am using this method to delete the validation error and calling the following inside the constructor of my form.

```
 this.nameCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(destroyed$) //this will clear the subscription
      )
      .subscribe(value =>
          this.removeFormControlError(
            this.nameCtrl, "nameValdidator")
        );
```

the problem with this code is that because of the way i save the user inputs, valueChanges constantly gets triggered and will just always delete my error message. I have tried working around with the touched & dirty property, but I am not very happy about this solution and also did not always work.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Implement a custom ErrorStateMatcher that matches your needs. See [this article](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-material/angular-material-custom-errorstatematcher).

Comment: Can't you wrap the removeFormControlError function inside an if with the condition "this.nameCtrl.invalid"?

Answer (score 0):

valueChanges observable emits values every time the form control's value changes, including when you programmatically set a value.

add a boolean flag userInteracted and check it

```
this.nameCtrl.valueChanges
  .pipe(takeUntil(destroyed$))
  .subscribe(value => {
    if (this.userInteracted) {
      this.removeFormControlError(this.nameCtrl, "nameValdidator");
    }
  });
```

then update your view

```
<input [formControl]="nameCtrl" (blur)="userInteracted = true">
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it's not a great idea use setError(null)

Typical you use a variable "submitted"

```
submitted:boolean=false;

submit()
{
   this.submitted=true;
}
```

Your .html like

```
<input formControlName="control" (input)="submitted=false"/>
<div *ngIf="submitted && 
            form.get('control').invalid">
   Error
</div>
<button (click)="submitted=true">submit</button>
```

or, using a .css like

```
  .error{
    display:none
  }
  .submitted input.ng-invalid+.error{
    display:block
  }
```

Some like:

```
<div [class.submitted]="submitted">
  <input formControlName="control" (input)="submitted=false"/>
  <div class="error">
    Error
  </div>
  ...
  <button (click)="submitted=true">submit</button>
</div>
```

A example of the second approach in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vy87xx?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)